# remove a particular array element from mongodb on clicking the element

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, ejs

I'm using this code for removing a particular array element stored in MongoDB when clicked that from the app. But this code is not working.

schema structure looks like this -

**const tagsSchema = new Schema({
    category: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    tname: { type: Array }
}, { _id: true });**

Below is the code I'm using for removing array element from db -

**Tags.updateOne({ tname: req.params.name }, { $pull: { _id: [req.params.id] } })**

For example - **"tname": "technical", "nontechnical"**

Now, technical is being clicked in the app to remove, but with the code I'm using it's not getting removed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more information about what you have tried to resolve your problem. What do you mean by "not working?" Is there a particular error? It's also helpful to provide more code as context.

Comment: I'm not getting any specific error but not able to remove the selected element, and getting that selected element as undefined in terminal.
I don't know if that piece of code is right for removing an array element

Answer (score 0):

you can use directly your element_value without `[]` after your array field, like below..

```
Tags.updateOne({tname: req.params.name}, { $pull: { your_array_field: req.params.id } } )
```

Comment: This didn't work either, can't find the clicked element in the app. getting undefined when printing the value for **{ tname: req.params.name }**

the clicked element is not accessed in the db I think.

Comment: Ok you should check your front then, where the value 'req.params.name' is coming from. Query seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the specific tag by its "**_id**" and then remove the particular name from the "**tname**" array.

```
Tags.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { $pull: { tname: req.params.name } })
```